# Detect if iOS app is in foreground from WatchKit extension

Tags: ios, watchkit

Since `+ openParentApplication:reply:` only opens the iOS app in the background, is there a way to detect if the app has been opened by the user and adapt the extension's behaviour accordingly?

*Edit:* Also, how could a mechanism work that notifies the extension once the app's status changes?

Answer (score 0):

You could check [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] and send something in the reply that indicates how you're running.

Comment: Yes, I imagined something like that. See my edit: I would probably be notified in the extension when the app's background status changes and now I'm looking for another way to do that instead of pulling every second or so.

Comment: You could post a local notification the watch kit extension handles those

Comment: I don't think Local Notifications work for my context but I might in fact try Darwin Notifications https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/MacOSXNotifcationOv/DarwinNotificationConcepts/DarwinNotificationConcepts.html